# Powershell - Run scriptline as current user, and not ICE admin user

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have a script running different queries through my "admin" AD account from Powershell ICE. And in the end i am exporting my variable to a csv file. Opening the new exported csv file with Excel and applying a custom Excel macro from my PERSONAL.XLSB folder with specified path.

The issue i am having is that whenever i try to make my script open info.csv (array output file).

```
$FilePath = 'C:\info.csv'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
```

It opens info.csv as my Powershell ICE "admin" AD account logically ofcourse.
How can i make $FilePath run-as my current user and not the ps1 admin-AD account?

Answer (score 0):

Run that script in a separate instance of Powershell, that is launched without extra options as "run as administrator" or run as exact user you want that script to run, of course providing credentials if it's not a logged-in user. For example, run a `cmd.exe`, there launch a `powershell` and there launch your script via copy+paste or sourcing a ps1 file.

Comment: Isn't there any way doing that as oneline on the bottom of my script file? Since all above is applied inside the script so far. I am doing automatisation process of our AD environment where i install computers and need to query info on clients on our install centre to see which is "done".

So opening my info.csv file in the same instance of Powershell, but Run-As: 
current-user would be the final piece. Instead of having to first run my PS1 and then opening Excel manually or a new Powershell instance to do the final part.

Comment: I think no, because since you will be launching a *child* process, it will inherit credentials from master process, and that one is already running under a user you don't want to use for that. Otherwise, you can invoke a `runas.exe` or `Start-Process -credential` as a means to launch a process as different user, but you'll need to explicitly supply that process with credentials.

Comment: Ok maybe i will have to realize i have to do those two things separately. Here is the output from my Powershell script Array inside the info.csv file. 

[url=https://i.postimg.cc/nryMgnrh/Desired-output-formatting.png[/url]

So what i am doing is. 
1. Get computers.txt 
2. Create a session to computers {each} 
3. Gather/query information i need into variables
4. Create custom-object array 
5. output results from $output to CSV 
6. Start CSV file within the script 
7. Run macro from Personal.xlsb

so would be nice to be able to run Excel with my current-user instead of ICE admin.

Comment: You start a CSV? So, determine where does Excel lie and fiddle with `Start-Process` feeding it `excel.exe` and your CSV, then check whether the macro is actually available.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick (tested with simple macro on csv)...
Open your Personal.XLSB (non-admin user path) with the same $Excel object as another workbook. Macro will then be available to run against your CSV.

[How to use powershell to run personal macro with different paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789954/how-to-use-powershell-to-run-personal-macro-with-different-paths)

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$wbPersonalXLSB = $excel.workbooks.open("C:\Users\[Non-Admin User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")
$FilePath = "[path to csv]\test.csv"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $false
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$excel.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB![macro name]")
$wbPersonalXLSB.Close()
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the issue im facing is also the Excel application opens the csv file without my AD 365 license. How can i force $Filepath to run as my current AD computer user and not my Admin AD account that is running PS ICe?